# Updating app on Heroku without loosing link to images

Tags: heroku

I have an app on Heroku, where users can add images. When I update this app `git push heroku master`, all the images disappear, leaving only broken links. Do you know how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku has particular restrictions on their filesystem, as it's [read only](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem).

You can only write into the public and tmp folders.
Though, those folders aren't persisted accross deployments.
This means you cannot rely on them to store files and images.

You need to send the files to a tierce party, like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage).
Most of the file upload and image processing (like [carrierwave](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)) will allow you to send the files to S3, or any other party.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku doesn't have a persistent file store. You need to store the files on a service such as [Amazon Simple Storage Solution](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (S3). For more information see Heroku's [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). In addition you can check our Heroku's documentation on how to setup S3 [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku do not preserve data on their servers so your images dissapear. Try using some external storage like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or store them in DB.