# How do I deploy local images from Refinery CMS to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms, pg

I developed my app with Refinery and I just deployed to Heroku. 
Everything works, except the images that were added to the pages through the CMS. To be more clear, the ones uploaded locally using the route:

> edit page > add image > upload > choose files > save > insert

The steps that I took for deployment were:

```
# push to repo
git push heroku master
# reset DB
heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_SILVER_URL
PGUSER=rails PGPASSWORD=rails heroku pg:push default_dev HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_SILVER_URL --app app-name-0000
```

Everything seems to go smooth, except for:

1. The images uploaded to the CMS locally are missing/broken in Heroku.

I don't know if it is relevant, but the final output that I get is this:

```
...
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for INDEX index_refinery_users_on_slug
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for INDEX index_seo_meta_on_id
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for INDEX unique_schema_migrations
WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 1
```

I assumed that the images are stored in the database, so they should be pushed as well, right?

There is no problem with the app or the database, as I can use the CMS to re-upload each image to the pages that needs them.

Please point me into the right direction.

Comment: exact duplicate of [Updating app on Heroku without loosing link to images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521683/updating-app-on-heroku-without-loosing-link-to-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you need to serve assets through Amazon S3. Check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037952/how-to-set-up-refinerycms-with-heroku-and-amazon-aws-assets?rq=1). Whomever wrote it is a hero, and explains the whole process pretty well. You'll need to set up a bucket on Amazon AWS and provide the access info to heroku, and do some funny business with asset pre-compilation.
I'd be very interested to know if you can get your images to work without following the instructions on the linked page.

Comment: Followed the one for Refinery: http://refinerycms.com/guides/amazon-s3-for-uploads